# Is it possible to edit a wordpress category with Gutenberg?

Tags: customization, categories, block-editor

i woud like to use Gutenberg to create custom category layouts. Is that possible somehow to activate it for categories?

Comment: No. At this stage it’s limited to posts and pages.

Comment: Categories are terms, like tags are terms. They would need to be posts to work in the block editor

Comment: Hmm to bad, i wanted to avoid any bloated pagebuilder in my new theme.

Comment: Are you trying to create a page that displays a layout for a specific category and loads posts from that category in it?  Your best bet would be to create a custom template for that category's `archive.php` file.  I don't think a bloated page builder is the solution you're looking for if I'm understanding this correctly.